# Update Twilio capability token in background

Tags: ios, iphone, twilio

I'm developing a VoIP application for iOS using Twilio iOS SDK.

The application should always be online, it should always be able to receive an incoming call. I. e. it should be able to live in background for several days or several weeks.

But the maximum expiration period of Twilio capability token is 24 hours. So, the application has to periodically update the capability token.
Is there a reliable way to update the token in background?

The only solution I found is to update the token in TCDeviceDelegate's method device:didStopListeningForIncomingConnections:.

But this solution is unreliable: if updating of the token fails, there is no means to retry the update.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Would it be an option for you to instead of updating the capability token manually, you listened to a callback from TCDevice? One of it's callbacks is called `TCDeviceIncomingStateOffline` and according to the documentation:

> the `TCDevice` may enter the `TCDeviceIncomingStateOffline` states because
>   the capabilities have expired. In these cases, the capabilities will
>   need to be updated. If the device is currently listening for incoming
>   connection, it will restart the listening process (if permitted) using
>   these updated capabilities.

So if you were to listen to a change in TCDevice where it becomes offline, you could easily then refresh the token. The listening process will then only start when the capabilities are updated.

Hope this helps you